# Why does cut (dplyr) shows negative values in R?

Tags: r

Can't post my exact data frame here but below is an example of my data. Column A is unique and B is numbers.

```
    A   B
    x   1.222
    y   3.290
    z   400.99
    ........
```

Below is my summary of data for B.

```
   Min.   :    0.556
   Mean   :  458.615
   Median :  151.960
   Max.   :23661.228
```

I wanted to divide B into different 5 groups of value (each group has approximately the same count value as the other 4) with below code using dplyr.

```
    data %>%
        mutate(range = cut(B, 5))
```

However, my output shows up with very strange looking values of B (either negative and very large) like below. This does not make sense as my min is 0.556 and there are no negative values in my dataset.

```
    range        
    (-23.1,4.73e+03]
    (4.73e+03,9.46e+03]
    .......
```

Could you please help me explain why does it show up like that? I used this code before and it worked fine for other data frame. Is there a better way to divide B into 5 equal ranges of values?

Comment: From the `?cut` help page: "When breaks is specified as a single number, the range of the data is divided into breaks pieces of equal length, and then the outer limits are moved away by 0.1% of the range to ensure that the extreme values both fall within the break intervals. (If x is a constant vector, equal-length intervals are created, one of which includes the single value.)" So you have `0.556-(23661.228-0.556)*.001 == -23.1`

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, it makes sense now. This is certainly not what I intended to do.  I wanted to create 5 different ranges for B but each one has approximately the same count of values as the other 4.

Comment: Then maybe you want `quantile()` Something like `breaks<-quantile(data$B, seq(0,1, length.out=6))` and then `cut(data$B, breaks)`

Comment: Check function `ntile` from `dplyr`.

Comment: @AntoniosK Thanks! ntile does break my data into 5 groups but it ranks 1,2,3,4,5. How do I check what is the value ranges of each category?

Comment: You can create a process that groups by rank (1,2,...5) and returns the min and max value of your variable for each rank.

Comment: @AntoniosK Thank you for the suggestion!